# How to use [(ngModel)] with a value that gets initialized after the component

Tags: angular, promise, observable, ngmodel

I have a variable call it 'x' that waits for the promise to resolve to get initialized. I also want to use 'x' in the component.html with

```
<input [(ngModel)]='x' />
```

but since the value is undefined at first I get this error
Cannot read property 'x' of undefined.

Is there a way to use it with the input field ??

Comment: Is that 'x' an independent variable or is it a field in some other object?

Comment: it represents some data that I am getting from the server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because you did not initialize the variable. Either you can do that in the component or use an `*ngIf` so that the input will only be active once it has got value.

```
<div *ngIf="x">
    <input [(ngModel)]="x"/> 
</div>
```

If the value to be bind is a field in an undefined object, you can also use the elvis operator `?`.

```
<input [ngModel]="object?.x" (ngModelChange)="object.x=$event"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

1.Initialize the variable as empty at first

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  x : any = '';
}
```

2.Toggle a loader on promise resolve

```
this.loader = true;
  performFakeCall().then(function(result) {
    this.loader = false;
    //...
  });
```

3.Show loading on UI until promise is resolved

```
<div *ngIf="loader == false">
  <input [(ngModel)]="x"/> 
</div>
<div class="css-loader" *ngIf="loader == true">
   //...show loader
</div>
```